# How do I record a MediaStream without using MediaRecorder?

Tags: javascript, ffmpeg, webrtc, mediastream, simple-peer

So I made this node js server that will act as another peer that will join a room and will gather all the streams,
But I am not able to find any way of converting this stream into a webm or any audio file.

```
    peers[connUserSocketId].on('stream', (stream) => {
      console.log('new stream came');
      streams = [...streams, stream];
    });
```